# FullCalendar - First day in Month View - Event spans from previous day ignoring nextDayThreshold

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on a calendar to display on-call shifts. They are 24 hour shifts from 8am to 8am the next day.

```
{
  title: 'Shift 1',
  start: '2017-09-30T08:00:00',
  end:   '2017-10-01T08:00:00'
},
```

I've turned off spanning by using:

```
nextDayThreshold: "09:00:00"
```

It's working well and only displaying the shifts on their start day. However, the first day shown in the monthly view shows the spanned events from the previous day. These events don't display the time and are left-aligned in the cell.

Here is a JSbin example - The issue is visible in the October view on the 1st: http://jsbin.com/sibehix/11/edit?html,js,output

This is causing some confusion among users. Is there a way to have it respect the nextDayThreshold like the other days? I'm using fullcalendar-3.7.0.

Comment: interestingly if you go back a month and view September, it displays properly and doesn't leak into the next day. I wonder if you've discovered a bug. https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Reporting-Bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I reported the issue and it’s been confirmed: http://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3943